# CLOUD SQL - Can’t save ‘add auth IP’ settings in Google Cloud console

Tags: google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-console

I want to authorize/add a IP under Cloud sql ‘Access Control’ in Cloud console, I can add new IP, but when I click the SAVE button, it does not seem to function or nothing happens when I click the SAVE button, not even an err message is thrown.

We have in the past added many IPs without any issue, but now it's buggy. Seems to be an issue in Cloud Console UI?

Comment: Hi there. I'm Chris from Cloud SQL. I see the problem here, the trick to add a new IP is not to press "Add Item" after entering the Name/IP, and instead go to the bottom and just press Save. When you press "Add Item", it thinks you are trying to add a second IP address, and so the Save button is disabled. This is a usability bug which I will file with a high priority today. Thanks for reporting this!

Comment: Thanks Chris for immediate reply.Now how to add ip as we r blocked.How long it ll take to fix?

Comment: As this usability bug is not yet fixed, you will need to remove empty (blank) network field or empty Application ID and then click on the Save button,

Comment: Thanks Kamran, now blank applicaion id saved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the Cloud SQL team member CF Lewis explained, this is a UI usability issue. You need to click "save", not "add item". If you previously clicked "add item", delete the blank entry and click save once you have put in the IP / App ID you want to allow as a client to your instance.